# Attempting to upload multiple files returns array of nil values (Rails App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm attempting to upload multiple files using a form inside a Rails 2.3.18 application. I've added `:multipart => true` to my form and `:multiple => true` to my `file_field` tag. The names portion of the `file_field` tag is `images[]`.

I am able to add multiple images in the browser and successfully submit the form. However, the images portion of the params shows `[nil, nil]` in the controller for however many images I submitted. I've included the form below (it is written in HAML).

```
- form_for :message, :url => post_url, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => "order-details-form"} do |form|
 = form.text_area :content, :placeholder => t(:type_message_here, :scope => :std)
 = form.file_field 'images[]', :multiple => true
 = form.submit t(:send, :scope => :bpt), :class => "io-button"
```

Comment: Have you tried `file_field :images, multiple: true`? using a string name for the field will break the nesting of attributes.

Comment: also, show your model, and you controller action and strong_params method

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you for your help arieljuod.